# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'. ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm just a beginner in ASP.NET Core. I have a column in the customers table (SQL Server) of date type. I want to update the customer status in the program but when trying to execute the update method I get the error :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Customers>> UpdateCustomerStatus(int customer_id, char customer_status)
{
    var dbcustomers = await _context.client_customers.FindAsync(customer_id);

    if (dbcustomers == null)
        return NotFound("Customer Not Found");
    if(customer_status == 'Y' || customer_status == 'N')
    {
        dbcustomers.customer_status = customer_status;
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid Status");
    }
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok(await _context.clients.ToListAsync());
}
```

I tried changing the data type in the customer model class but it didn't work and I got the error to explicitly map the property.

```
public DateOnly join_date { get; set; }
```

Do I change something in the table or convert the data type in the program?

Comment: I don't see how the snippet relates to the question? Property `join_date` (which _should be_ `JoinDate`, btw) isn't affected here, at all.

Comment: It is hard to say from the information you have posted, but my guess would be that the customer type uses different types for one or more properties between the database and the code.

Comment: Anyway, if that's the case, you cannot just do `string myDate = somethingThatIsADateTime;` neither types have explicit or implict conversion operators defined for each other. If you need to make such a transition in your DTO/Model structure, you need to map them explicitly. ( by using ToString and DateTime.Parse or equivalent methods )

Comment: Based on the error message and the code you've provided, it appears that customer_status in your database is of type string, while in your C# model class, it is defined as char. To resolve this issue, you should ensure that the data types match between your database schema and your model class

Comment: to me, you have something in your model that does that. Here I don't see what could cause this. Show the model

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample from the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and my test result.

Just like what we have in the comments, the error points to an issue that might relate to your model or DTO which set a string to store the date time. Then when we use ef-core to save the model to the table we got this exception, we need to modify the model.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(movie);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(movie);
}

 public class Movie
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string? Title { get; set; }
     [DataType(DataType.Date)]
     public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
     public string? Genre { get; set; }
     public decimal Price { get; set; }
 }
 
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Test result.

[image]